# Is this an error in index.js or did I forget to install something?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I try to connect a MongoDB in my application, but when I run

```bash
node index.js
```

I get the following error message:

```
node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\admin.js:62
            session: options?.session,
                             ^
    
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Actually I think that my Code is correct, but if this the case why it occurs?
My Code is as follows:

```js
const express = require('express')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
const routes = require('./routes/routes')
    
const cors = require('cors')
    
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    
const app = express()
    
    
app.use(cors({
    credential: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200']
}))
// Enable CORS with credentials and custom headers
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200', credentials: true }));
    
const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:4200/register', 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
    
app.use(cors(corsOptions)) 
    
app.use(cookieParser())
    
app.use(express.json())
    
app.use("/api", routes)
    
const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.bm3qkcb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(()=>{
    console.log("DB Connected")
    app.listen(5000, () =>
    console.log("server is running on port", 5000))
})
```

Of course, I replaced USERNAME and PASSWORD in real testing.
At least, I get no Syntax errors, therefore I think the code is correct. But what can be then the problem? Did I maybe forget to install some dependencies or something?

Comment: Which node.js version are you on?

Comment: could you give us package.json, to know what version of mongo do you use?

Comment: Check your node version. Optional chaining was added in version 14. At the time of writing this comment in December 2023, the current version is 21. If you read this comment in the future, it will probably be another version.